# Probability of a set that has infinite Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Forgive, for the title didn't know how to name this questions. Please change to something better.

Let $B_1(n)$ denote a unit ball around $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Suppose that for every $n$ there exists a set $E_n \subset B_1(n)$ such that $\mu(E_n)=c$, that is every unit interval around an integer has a subset of Lebesgue measure $c$.

Let $v$ be some probability measure. Is it correct that the set $E= \cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} E_n$ has probability measure $\nu(E)=c$? In other words, the probability of 'hitting' a set $E$ is $c$.

**Here is my argument:** I used [the following theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure) from wiki ( I would appreciate a good reference)

> **Theorem:** Any σ-finite measure μ on a space X is equivalent to a probability
>   measure on X: let $V_n$, $n ∈ N$, be a covering of X by pairwise
>   disjoint measurable sets of finite μ-measure, and let $w_n$, $n ∈ N$,
>   be a sequence of positive numbers (weights) such that
>
> \begin{align}  \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n = 1.  \end{align} The measure ν
>    defined by
>
> \begin{align} \nu(A) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n \frac { \mu (A \cap
>  V_n) } {\mu (V_n)}  \end{align} is then a probability measure on X
>   with precisely the same null sets as $μ$.

From the above result, letting $X=\mathbb{R^+}$ and $A=E$ and using the fact that Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite.

Also, letting $V_n= B_1(n)$, for $n=0$ let $V_0= [0, 1/2)$.

We have that
\begin{align}
\nu(E)= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n \frac { \mu (E \cap
  B_1(n)) } {\mu ( B_1(n))} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n  \mu (E \cap
  B_1(n)) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n  \mu (E_n)= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty w_n  c=c
\end{align}

Is this argument correct? If so, how can I improve it? If not correct please help.
I would also appreciate a reference to the theorem above.

Thank you very much.

**Bounty:**  For the bounty I would like to have a reference ( a book or a paper) that shows the above theorem.

Comment: If $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ and $\mu(B_1(n))=1$ that seems to hold up just fine. However, I am not sure why you are letting $V_n=B_1(n)$ since you never *use* $V_n$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp I am just matching my problem to the theorem. In the theorem $V_n$ are the covering of $X$. In my case, I call them $B_1(n)$ and they are the coverings for $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Please let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: You should edit your Q to specify that $\mu(E_m\cap E_n)=0$ when $m\ne n$, otherwise we could have $E_{2n}=E_{2n+1}=(2n,2n+1)$ for each $n$ with $c=1$ but a probability of $1/2$.

Comment: @user254665 . Thanks, noted. But otherwise does it look correct?

Comment: Yes  you are right.Consider $\lim _{x\to \infty} ( \int_{-x}^x \chi (E(y))dy)/2x$. How else would you define the odds?

Comment: @user254665 Ok. Thank thanks. Do you happen to know where I can find the reference to the theorem? I found it on wiki. Is there a textbook that might show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking your application of the theorem that you cite is not correct, because your $V_n$ are not pairwise disjoint: $(0, \dfrac 1 2) \subset V_0 \cap V_1$ and $(n, n+1) \subset V_n \cap V_{n+1}$. If I were you I would choose $V_0$ as you do and then $V_n = [n - \dfrac 1 2, n + \dfrac 1 2)$.

This mistake is not really severe, though, and you may leave your $V_n$ as they are provided you use the slightly different form of the same theorem that can be found on [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/anysigmafinitemeasureisequivalenttoaprobabilitymeasure) and that does not require disjointness (if you see a web error at the given address, just scroll down that page).

Save for this detail, your proof is correct.

Comment: Alex thank you for the reference